# Median of nearest neighbors and count of multi-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, median

Out of an array filled with floats (in this example with ints for simplicity), the goal is to create two new np.arrays (with the same shape as data):

- First np.array with the the median for the nearest neighbours around the element and the element itself, so 9 values.
- Second np.array with the count of neighbors and the element itself. No value (when you go outside of the borders there are no values) or -99 should not be counted.

Example code I'm using right now: (note that the real shape of 'data' is 360,802 filled with floats)

```
data= np.array([
    [  5,  8,  5,  3, -1,  7, -5,-99, -2,  5], 
    [ -2,  4,  1,-99,  1,  9, -1, -2,  5,  9],
    [  0,  4,  1,  0, -3,  2, -1,  1,  3, -1],
    [ -2,  9, -1,  3,  1,  3,  2,  0, -7,  2],
    [  4,-99,  4,  0, -9, -1, -1,-99,  1, -4],
    [  1, -4,  7,  1,  6,  6, -2, -9,  4,  9]
    ], np.float32)
    

distFmOriginX=1
distFmOriginY=1

medianArr       = np.empty([data.shape[0],data.shape[1]], dtype = float)
nrOfCountsArr   = np.zeros([data.shape[0],data.shape[1]], dtype = int)

for x in range(data.shape[0]):
 for y in range(data.shape[1]):
  cnt=0
  arr=[]
  if data[x][y]==-99:
   medianArr[x][y]=-99
   nrOfCountsArr[x][y]=-99
   continue
  xAlt = x-distFmOriginX 
  yAlt = y-distFmOriginY

  for i in range((2*distFmOriginX)+1):
   for j in range((2*distFmOriginY)+1):
    if (xAlt+i)>=data.shape[0] or (xAlt+i)<0:
     continue
    if (yAlt+j)>=data.shape[1] or (yAlt+j)<0:
     continue
    if data[xAlt+i][yAlt+j]==-99:
     continue
    arr.append(data[xAlt+i][yAlt+j])
    cnt+=1
  if cnt>0:
   medianArr[x][y]     = np.median(arr)
   nrOfCountsArr[x][y] = cnt
```

This results in the wished outcome:

```
medianArr:
 [[  4.5   4.5   4.    1.    3.    0.   -1.  -99.    5.    5. ]
 [  4.    4.    3.5 -99.    1.5  -1.    0.   -1.    2.    4. ]
 [  2.    1.    2.    1.    1.5   1.    1.    0.    1.    2.5]
 [  4.    2.5   2.    0.    0.   -1.    0.5   0.5   0.5   0. ]
 [  1.  -99.    2.    1.    1.    1.   -0.5 -99.    0.5   1.5]
 [  1.    4.    1.    2.5   0.5  -1.   -1.   -1.    1.    2.5]]
nrOfCountsArr:
 [[  4   6   5   5   5   6   5 -99   5   4]
 [  6   9   8 -99   8   9   8   8   8   6]
 [  6   9   8   8   8   9   9   9   9   6]
 [  5   8   8   9   9   9   8   8   8   6]
 [  5 -99   8   9   9   9   8 -99   8   6]
 [  3   5   5   6   6   6   5   5   5   4]]
```

Right now the above working solution with old fashioned multi-nested for-loops is in place. This takes too much processing time and I'm sure there is a
numpy/scipy solution I'm unaware of. Searching a lot delivered this solution, but this is for the average instead of the median:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254753/calculate-the-average-of-neighbor-pixels-for-raster-edge

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

def average_convolve2d(data):
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3))

    array_sum = convolve2d(
        data, kernel, mode='same',
        boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)

    num_counts = convolve2d(
        np.ones(data.shape), kernel, mode='same',
        boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)

    return array_sum / num_counts

avg = average_convolve2d(data)
```

This method is great and really fast (0.01s versus 10.5s). I've been puzzling if I can do the same or something similar for the median (instead of the average in this example) and return both arrays (median and number counts within the window).

*Side note: In the future I want to be able to specify the amount of elements away from the main element in the x and y dimension.
For example: 1 step left and right in x-dimension (distFmOriginX=1), and 2 steps up and down in the y-dimension (distFmOriginY=2), including the main element, resulting in 15 values.*

Hope there is one of you out there with a brilliant solution that I've not come across yet.

Comment: You didn't add the expected output, is well explained what you need, but adding the output will let us verify our results

Comment: What means "no value around the borders"?

Comment: You are right, let me edit the message

Comment: I've added the wished output and added my currently used (inefficient) code

Comment: How do you count the neighbors though? For example, the element in the top left corner has only 3 neighbors, but you output 4. Does that mean you count the element itself as a neighbor?

Comment: Yes, indeed, the element itself is also counted. It's the sum of the neighbors and the actual element. Except when -99 or empty, as explained in the start post.

Comment: I don't understand the desired output for the median. For example, in the upper left corner how can you get the value `4.5`, if the value is not even present in the input array?

Comment: That is because the amount of numbers is even, if that occurs the median algorithm will average the two median numbers. If the amount of numbers is odd, it will choose the middle value. That is how the median is defined.

Comment: Fair point, I was considering a 3x3 kernel where there's always an odd number of neighbours + the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [5, 8, 5, 3, -1, 7, -5, -99, -2, 5],
    [-2, 4, 1, -99, 1, 9, -1, -2, 5, 9],
    [0, 4, 1, 0, -3, 2, -1, 1, 3, -1],
    [-2, 9, -1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, -7, 2],
    [4, -99, 4, 0, -9, -1, -1, -99, 1, -4],
    [1, -4, 7, 1, 6, 6, -2, -9, 4, 9]
], np.float32)

# create padded array with np.nan around the edges
padded = np.pad(data, 1, 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)

# set -99 to np.nan to ignore in the median
padded[padded == -99] = np.nan

# create sliding window over the padded array
window = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(padded, (3, 3)).reshape((6, 10, -1))

# compute the median
median = np.nanmedian(window, axis=2)

# compute the count
count = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(window), axis=2)

# reset the elements to -99
median[data == -99] = -99
count[data == -99] = -99

print(median)
print("--")
print(count)
```

**Output**

```
[[  4.5   4.5   4.    1.    3.    0.   -1.  -99.    5.    5. ]
 [  4.    4.    3.5 -99.    1.5  -1.    0.   -1.    2.    4. ]
 [  2.    1.    2.    1.    1.5   1.    1.    0.    1.    2.5]
 [  4.    2.5   2.    0.    0.   -1.    0.5   0.5   0.5   0. ]
 [  1.  -99.    2.    1.    1.    1.   -0.5 -99.    0.5   1.5]
 [  1.    4.    1.    2.5   0.5  -1.   -1.   -1.    1.    2.5]]
--
[[  4   6   5   5   5   6   5 -99   5   4]
 [  6   9   8 -99   8   9   8   8   8   6]
 [  6   9   8   8   8   9   9   9   9   6]
 [  5   8   8   9   9   9   8   8   8   6]
 [  5 -99   8   9   9   9   8 -99   8   6]
 [  3   5   5   6   6   6   5   5   5   4]]
```

#### Step by Step

1. The idea is to create the windowed array using [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy.pad) + [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view), setting the values to be ignored as `nan`.
2. The second step is using the reduce functions [`nanmedian`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmedian.html#numpy.nanmedian) and [`count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy.count_nonzero) to compute the desired results.
3. Finally set back the `-99` values to match the exact output.

Comment: Damn I was in the process of writing an answer with the same reasoning, good call on using `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` =)

Comment: This works great! Thanks! What if I want to reintroduce distFmOriginX and distFmOriginY in your solution, so I can play with the window size?